# Built-in python dictionary function behaves differently

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the code below e is my dictionary . ee is the shallow copy of my dictionary created by using the copy method.

```
e = {'a': 100, 'b': [1, 2]}
ee = e.copy()
```

After the first statement below, the value in ee also changes .

```
e['b'][0] = 'foo'  # {'a': 100, 'b': ['foo', 2]}
```

After the below statement, the value in ee does not change.

```
e['a'] = 300     # {'a': 100, 'b': ['foo', 2]}
```

Can anyone explain the reason for the same or provide link to the question if it is already addressed.

Comment: You answered it yourself - `ee` is a shallow copy of `e`, they are their own objects but the value associated with the key `'b'` points to the same list.

Comment: That's what _shallow_ means

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, this is a shallow copy.
In order to create an "independent" copy, use:

```
from copy import deepcopy
ee = deepcopy(e)
```

Now you can change `e` without affecting `ee`